# Regex for validation only when length is 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, fluentvalidation

I am trying to validate that a string is 5 characters long OR if it has a leading zero it can be 6. I am having trouble with the OR part of this, so far my regex is `^(0)[a-zA-Z0-9]{5}$` but this is checking for a 0 and then 5 digit number, so 5 digit numbers without zero are invalid.

Is there a regex that checks for a leading zero only in the case when the length is 6?

Comment: Maybe `"^0?[0-9]{5}$"`? Why do you say *5 digit number*, but included letters to the character class?

Comment: use '?' immediately after (0) to make it optional. `0?` More info: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/46/c-regular-expressions-cheat-sheet

Comment: Did my answer solved your issue ?

Answer (score 7):

Make the leading `0` optional:

```
^0?[a-zA-Z0-9]{5}$
```

⬆This will match 5 characters (in the ranges `a` to `z`, `A` to `Z` and `0` to `9`) leaded, or not, by a `0`.

If you're looking for 5 or 6 **digits**:

```
^0?\d{5}$
```

Comment: That will match more than 5 or 6 digit numbers.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew OP isn't clear: *I am trying to validate that a string is 5 **characters** long*